# Using htaccess I want to redirect a partcular folder from old folder to new folder. The

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Using htaccess I want to redirect a particular folder from old folder to new folder.  But there is a php file in root folder with same name which also gets redirected.

So for example.

```
example.com/name/
```

Should redirect to:

```
example.com/newname/
```

which works fine, but I also have:

```
example.com/name.php
```

Which should not redirect but it goes to:

```
example.com/newname
```

So how to redirect folder but exclude file from the redirection?

Here is what we tried.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^abc\.php  [C]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^abc$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/xyz/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use make sure to use correct restricted regex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^name/?$ /newname/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: THanks anubhava. So what will be the condition in this case?

Comment: No additional conditions needed since URI pattern itself acts like a condition. Pattern `^name/?$` will only match `/name` OR `/name/` but it won't match `/name.php`

Comment: +1 looks right to me, unless @VIP potentially have other rules on his `.htaccess` and is placing yours at the wrong place. He might also need `-MultiViews` to avoid the folder redirection.

Comment: Its not working. As Prix is saying I am checking other rules.

Comment: If you have other rules also make sure this is very first rule in your .htaccess. Also tell me for which URL it didn't work and where is this .htaccess located?